# Error creating bean with name 'FilterService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'filterDAO'

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm a beginner in spring and I have a problem in my code. When I try run back-end application I have the follow error:

I don't know what's the problem, because I followed an examples on foruns and tutorials

I think that the class FilterDAO cannot be injected on my Controoler FilterService but I don't know why.

Could you please help me on this bug?

Follow below the error and my classes

1 - Error in eclipse:

```
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'FilterService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'filterDAO': Error creating bean with name 'FilterDAO' defined in file [C:\Users\andrev\Documents\kaiju_project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\angularkaiju\WEB-INF\classes\com\motorola\gisele\persistence\moto4u\FilterDAO.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.motorola.gisele.persistence.moto4u.FilterDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'FilterDAO' defined in file [C:\Users\andrev\Documents\kaiju_project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\angularkaiju\WEB-INF\classes\com\motorola\gisele\persistence\moto4u\FilterDAO.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.motorola.gisele.persistence.moto4u.FilterDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doOptions(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:44)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.execute(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.run(ManagedSelector.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by:
```

I have one Rest class named 'FilterServiceRest' (follow below):

2 - FilterServiceRest.class

```
@Lazy
@CrossOrigin
@RestController("FilterService")
@RequestMapping("/filters")
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@DisableSecurity
public class FilterServiceRest extends RestService {

private static final String SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG_MSG = "Something went wrong. Try again in a few seconds!";

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FilterServiceRest.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private FilterDAO filterDAO;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/top-models", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity topModels() {
        List models = filterDAO.getTopModels();
        return ok(models);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/top-prices", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity topPrices() {
        List rangePrices = filterDAO.getTopPrices();
        return ok(rangePrices);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/top-features", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity topFeatures() {
        TopFeaturesVO features = filterDAO.getTopFeatures();
        return ok(features);
    }
```

}

I have one DAO class that will create EntityManager and execute query on database

3 - FilterDAO.class

```
@Lazy
@Repository("FilterDAO")
public class FilterDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FilterDAO.class.getName());
    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 25;

    private Moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration;

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public FilterDAO(Moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration){
        this.moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration = moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration;
        this.entityManager = moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration.createEntityManagerFactory("jirammi");
    }

    public List getTopModels() {
        String query =
        "Select moto4u.device.model, count(*) as quant from moto4u.filter inner join moto4u.device on moto4u.device.id = moto4u.filter.device_selected group by device_selected order by quant DESC";
        return this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }

    public List getTopPrices() {
        String query = "Select range_price, count(*) as quant from moto4u.filter group by range_price order by quant DESC";
        return this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }

     /**....**/
```

}

and finally I have one other class that set database configuration and execute query.

4 - Moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration.class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration.class.getName());

    private static final String MOTO4U_PUNIT_NAME = "Moto4uSQL";
    private static final String JDBC_CLASS_NAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver";
    private static final String LOCALHOST_NAME = "localhost";
    private static final String JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_USER = "javax.persistence.jdbc.user";
    private static final String JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_PASS = "javax.persistence.jdbc.password";
    private static final String JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_URL = "javax.persistence.jdbc.url";

    @Value("${cloudsql.moto4u.localdb.user}")
    private String localDBUser;

    @Value("${cloudsql.moto4u.localdb.password}")
    private String localDBPass;

    @Value("${cloudsql.moto4u.localdb.url}")
    private String localDBURL;

    // This flag is used to connect the local development machine to a remote MySQL server (i.e. Jirammi)
    @Value("${cloudsql.moto4u.flag.use-remotedb}")
    private Boolean useRemoteDB;

    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * This method is used by LocalDataStoreLoader.
     *
     * @param server the server to connect to when creating the EntityManagerFactory
     * @return an EntityManagerFactory
     */
    public EntityManager createEntityManagerFactory(String server) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        if(LOCALHOST_NAME.equals(server)){
            logger.info("EntityManagerFactory using localhost");
            properties.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_URL, localDBURL);
            properties.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_USER, localDBUser);
            properties.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_PASS, localDBPass);
        }

        properties.put("hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name", server);
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(MOTO4U_PUNIT_NAME, properties);

        if (em == null) {
            em = factory.createEntityManager();
        }

        return em;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error : 'FilterDAO' -> "Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"

```
private FilterDAO(){
        this.entityManager = moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration.createEntityManagerFactory("jirammi");
    }
```

here `moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration` is null, you didn't instanciate it

Comment: Hi vVyncent. I already instanciated the moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration but not working yet.

Comment: "private Moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration;"

here the field in FilterDAO is null

Comment: Hi Vyncent, thanks for your comment. I changed my FilterDAO.class (please look my update). Now the moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration does not null. but there is the error yet.

Comment: Same exception ?

Comment: yes, do you think that I need add annotation @PersistenceContext in entityManager declaration?

Comment: Well i'm quite surprised, as you added the moto4UCLoudSQLConfiguration as autowired, there is 'reason' the code will throw a null pointer here `    @Autowired
    public FilterDAO(Moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration){
        this.moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration = moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration;
        this.entityManager = moto4UCloudSQLConfiguration.createEntityManagerFactory("jirammi");
    }`